# flutter_bloc is it ok to store a variable inside bloc/cubit class

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit, flutter-cubit

i have a cubit named `AuthCubit` in which I have multiple functions related to authentication like login,resetPassword,...

the thing is all my functions need variable `phoneNumber` which is taken from user on on first screen, after checking if `phoneNumber` exists in server or not application navigates to different screens.

so my question is that is it ok to store `phoneNumber` in `AuthCubit` class and use it from there (like how it's done with Provider/ChangeNotifier)?
or should I make `AuthState` base class require a `phoneNumber` variable?

below is the code snippet from AuthCubit

```
class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
  final LoginWithCredentialsUsecase _loginWithCredentialsUsecase;
  final CheckPhoneNumberExistUsecase _checkPhoneNumberExistUsecase;
  final SendOTPTokenUsecase _sendOTPTokenUsecase;
  final VerifyOTPTokenUsecase _verifyOTPTokenUsecase;
  final SendResetPasswordOtpUsecase _sendResetPasswordOtpUsecase;
  AuthCubit(
      {required LoginWithCredentialsUsecase loginWithCredentialsUsecase,
      required CheckPhoneNumberExistUsecase checkPhoneNumberExistUsecase,
      required SendOTPTokenUsecase sendOTPTokenUsecase,
      required VerifyOTPTokenUsecase verifyOTPTokenUsecase,
      required SendResetPasswordOtpUsecase sendResetPasswordOtpUsecase,
      required VerifyResetPasswordOtpUsecase verifyResetPasswordOtpUsecase})
      : _loginWithCredentialsUsecase = loginWithCredentialsUsecase,
        _checkPhoneNumberExistUsecase = checkPhoneNumberExistUsecase,
        _sendOTPTokenUsecase = sendOTPTokenUsecase,
        _verifyOTPTokenUsecase = verifyOTPTokenUsecase,
        _sendResetPasswordOtpUsecase = sendResetPasswordOtpUsecase,
        super(AuthInitial());
 
  Future<void> loginWithCredentianls(
      {String password = '',
      required String phoneNumber,
      String otpCode = ''}) async {
    emit(AuthLoading());
    try {
      final driver = await _loginWithCredentialsUsecase(
          password: password, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, otpCode: otpCode);
      emit(AuthSuccess(driver: driver));
    } on LoginFieldsNotCorrectException catch (e) {
      emit(AuthException(message: e.message));
    } on LoginNoRemainingChangeDeviceException catch (e) {
      emit(AuthException(message: e.message));
    } on LoginNotADriverException catch (e) {
      emit(AuthException(message: e.message));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(AuthFailed(message: e.toString()));
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendOTPMessageToPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    emit(AuthLoading());
    try {
      final wasSuccess = await _sendOTPTokenUsecase(phoneNumber);
      if (wasSuccess) {
        emit(PhoneAuthOTPSent(phoneNumber: phoneNumber));
      } else {
        emit(phoneAuthFailedState);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit(phoneAuthFailedState);
    }
  }

  Future<void> checkPhoneAuthentication(String phoneNumber) async {
    emit(AuthLoading());
    try {
      final phoneNumberAuth = await _checkPhoneNumberExistUsecase(phoneNumber);
      if (phoneNumberAuth.isAuthenticated) {
        emit(PhoneAuthenticated(phoneNumber: phoneNumber));
      } else {
        emit(PhoneNotAuthenticated(
            message: phoneNumberAuth.message, phoneNumber: phoneNumber));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      emit(phoneAuthFailedState);
    }
  }

  Future<void> verifyOTPToken(String token, String phoneNumber) async {
    emit(AuthLoading());
    try {
      final wasSuccess = await _verifyOTPTokenUsecase(token, phoneNumber);
      if (wasSuccess) {
        emit(PhoneAuthOTPVerified(phoneNumber: phoneNumber, otpCode: token));
      } else {
        emit(PhoneAuthOTPNotVerified(
            message: 'کد وارد شده صحیح نیست', otpCode: token,phoneNumber: phoneNumber));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      emit(phoneAuthFailedState);
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendResetPasswordOtp(String phoneNumber) async {
    emit(AuthLoading());
    try {
      await _sendResetPasswordOtpUsecase(phoneNumber);
      emit(PhoneAuthOTPSent(phoneNumber: phoneNumber));
    } on ResetPasswordException catch (e) {
      emit(ResetPasswordExceptionState(message: e.message));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(phoneAuthFailedState);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is opinon-based... but I would say that yes it is, or at least can be, OK to store the phoneNumber in the AuthCubit. It depends on how AuthCubit is created with respect to phoneNumber.

If AuthCubit can exist without phoneNumber, and then phoneNumber is set at a later time, then you should let AuthState carry state(s) that reflect that phoneNumber is either set or not.

But if AuthCubit is never created, and can never be created without a phoneNumber present, then you can add phoneNumber as a final parameter to the AuthCubit class.

Comment: Tnx in my situation AuthCubit is created without a phone number and phone number is set after checkPhoneExists method and it would never change but none of the other methods would be called before that method the problem with the state procedure is that not all of the states would need a phoneNumber and many states would be emitted throughout of authentication procedure . I get what you mean and it sounds logicall to me but the amount of checking if the state is the right state that has phoneNumber would be too much